# How can build.gradle be configured to check for classes from src\main\java instead of src\test\java?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle project (converted from an original ANT project). The directory structure is as advised by gradle so my source is in src\main\java and test is in src\test\java.

However, because the package structure of src\test is almost exactly similar to src\main, during the test run phase in gradle, I get a bunch of

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

even though I can clearly see the code under ,say, **src\main\A.B.C\Y\X.java**. I am suspecting that while running the tests, the class to import is being searched under **src\test\A.B.C\Y** where, of course, the class X is not present

Comment: Both src/main/java and src/test/java are compiled and added to the classpath when running tests.  Can you show a complete example, and a complete error message?

Comment: Please post the beginning of the actual exception you get, the file path of the file that is missing, and the relevant parts of your build.gradle.

Comment: why would the path be "src\main\A.B.C\Y\X.java"? "Should be src\main\A\B\C\Y\X.java"